# Same query results in different execution time and nscanned. why?

Tags: mongodb

i run exactly same query but when i analyze the mongo log, i see that exection times and nscanned attributes are very different fro exactly same query. Any ideas? Logs are below.

```
Mon Jul  7 11:53:03.852 [conn13685] query news-data.news query: { query: { $and: [ { $or: [ { t: "F" } ] }, { $or: [ { s: "FRKS" } ] }, { $or: [ { l: "tr" } ] } ], f: false }, orderby: { d: -1 }, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" } } cursorid:7244510450672463669 ntoreturn:75 ntoskip:0 nscanned:13693 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:116740 nreturned:75 reslen:175088 116ms

Mon Jul  7 13:42:50.075 [conn13622] query news-data.news query: { query: { $and: [ { $or: [ { t: "F" } ] }, { $or: [ { s: "FRKS" } ] }, { $or: [ { l: "tr" } ] } ], f: false }, orderby: { d: -1 }, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" } } cursorid:7272408840112234507 ntoreturn:45 ntoskip:0 nscanned:462478 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 10 locks(micros) r:6869463 nreturned:45 reslen:112182 3734ms
```

Comment: One difference I see here is the "ntoreturn" value is 75 in one and 45 in the other. "ntoreturn" is the number of documents requested or limit value. I would recommend running both in the mongo shell with a .explain() appended which will show you the index use, running with both limit values.

Comment: there are also some logs that ntoreturn is same. So i think ntoreturn doest not cause the problem. Explain output is as follows:rs_b:PRIMARY> db.news.find({"$and":[{"$or":[{s:"FRKS"}]},{"$or":[{l:"tr"}]}],f:false}).sort({d:-1}).limit(45).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor news_locale_source_idx",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 45,
        "nscannedObjects" : 67,
        "nscanned" : 67,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 376,

Comment: Did you run the explain against the same data set? In this explain you are scanning 67 entries to provide a result. That much better than your results above. I would run against your secondary instances as well as your readPreference is "secondaryPreferred". Maybe your secondaries are missing indexes?

Comment: Yea, same data set. Also there is no secondary in the shard, just primary exists.

Answer (score 1):

This was already answered on MongoDB user Google Group, repeating for completeness:

You can see that one of those queries had to yield 10 times, which means to resume its work some of the documents it had already scanned may have been needed to be scanned again.

> numYields: 10

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didnt find any question in group. Can you send the question link if possible. Thanks.

Comment: oh right, you posted it to the wrong group (dev instead of user) https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-dev/iaXA1xyzgDg/kV6R-aGZZqwJ